# How could I get the List Value which contains KeyValuePair in C#?

Tags: c#, list, keyvaluepair

I want to find and element in List which is KeyValuePair and can't figure out how to get through the "

> Cannot apply operator == to operands of type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List'

" error. When I change the method to _adjacencyMatrix.FindIndex(from.GetNumer()) then I get "

> Argument int is not assignable to parameter type 'System
>   .Predicate

" Then when I change the method to _adjacencyMatrix.IndexOf(MakePair(from,to)) then I get the "

> Argument type'System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair' is not
>   assignable to parameter type 'System.Collections.Generic.List

" error. I don't know what I can do about it. Do you guys have any ideas? I'm new to C# although I've worked in C++. I attach the code below. There probably should be number instead of numer but I don't want to change it in my code.

```
using System.Windows.Documents;

namespace GPS
{
    public class Vertex
    {
        private int _numer;

        public Vertex(int numer)
        {
            this._numer = numer;
        }

        public void Deconstruct()
        {
        }

        public int GetNumer()
        {
            return this._numer;
        }
    }
}
```

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using GPS;

namespace GPS
{
    public class Edge
    {
        private float _distance;
        private KeyValuePair<Vertex, Vertex> _fromTo;

        public Edge(float distance, KeyValuePair<Vertex, Vertex> fromTo)
        {
            this._distance = distance;
            this._fromTo = fromTo;
        }

        public KeyValuePair<Vertex, Vertex> GetFromTo()
        {
            return _fromTo;
        }


        public float GetDistance()
        {
            return _distance;
        }

        public void SetDistance(float distance)
        {
            this._distance = distance;
        }

        public void Deconstruct()
        {
        }
    }
}
```

```
using System;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using System.Linq;
 using System.Net.Configuration;
 using System.Windows.Documents;
 using GPS;

 namespace GPS
 {
     public class Graph
     {
         private int _vertexNumber;
         private List _egdesMatrix;

         private List<List<Vertex>> _adjacencyMatrix;

         public Graf(int vertexNumber)
         {
             this._vertexNumber = vertexNumber;
             this._egdesMatrix = new List();
             this._adjacencyMatrix = new List<List<Vertex>>();
         }

         public void Deconstruct()
         {
         }

         public List GetEgdesMatrix()
         {
             return _egdesMatrix;
         }


         public bool IsOutOfRange(Vertex from, Vertex to)
         {
             return from.GetNumer() < 0 || to.GetNumer() < 0 ||
                    from.GetNumer() >= _vertexNumber || to.GetNumer() >= _iloscWierzcholkow;
         }

         private KeyValuePair<Vertex, Vertex> MakePair(Vertex from, Vertex to)
         {
             return new KeyValuePair<Vertex, Vertex>(from, to);
         }

         public bool IsThereAnEdge(Vertex from, Vertex to)
         {
             if (IsOutOfRange(from, to) != false) return false;
             for (var i = 0; i < _vertexNumber; i++)
             {
                 if (_adjacencyMatrix[from.GetNumer()]==to) ;
                 {
                     return true;
                 }
             }

             return false;
         }

 //list.Find(item => item > 20);
         public void DodajKrawedz(Vertex from, Vertex to, float odleglosc)
         {
             if (IsOutOfRange(from, to) == false && IsThereAnEdge(from, to) == false)
             {
                 _egdesMatrix.Add(MakePair(from, to));
             }
         }
     }
 }
```

Comment: Using `KeyValuePair<Vertex, Vertex>` for storing a `from` and `to` values doesn't look correct. You can use tuple or own class

Comment: Okay, I've changed it ;)

Answer (score 0):

That's because `_adjacencyMatrix` is of type `List<List<Vertex>>`. 

So when accessing `_adjacencyMatrix[from.GetNumer()]` you get `List<Vertex>` and it can not be compared to Vertex.

#### Update #1

Ok, according to your comment, if you want to search matrix and find KeyValuePair that mathes two Vertexes, you can do it like this:

```
var edgesMatrix = new List<KeyValuePair<Vertex, Vertex>>();

var from = new Vertex(1);
var to = new Vertex(2);

var pairsFromMatrix = edgesMatrix
    .Where(em => em.Key == from && em.Value == to);
```

Comment: Well, You're right I want to find in _edgesMatrix instead of _adjacencyMatrix. I have now:_egdesMatrix.IndexOf(MakePair(from, to));
                 if (_egdesMatrix.FindIndex(from.GetNumer()));
                 {
                     return true;
                 } And it still doesn't work. I get the error that says "Argument type'System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair is not assignable to parameter type T" or "Cannot resolve IndexOf" or "Cannot Resolve FindIndex" in two programs that have the same code.

Comment: Okay. Now I know how to compare the elements of KeyValuePair, how can I code it using general solution I mean: var pairsFromMatrix = _egdesMatrix//!!!
                    .Where(em => em.Key == from && em.Value == to);
                if (_edgesMatrix.FindIndex(MakePair(from, to))) ;
                ;
                {
                    return true;
                }

Comment: @Olga if you need to know, if pairsFromMatrix contains something, you can call `Any`. The code will be like this: `if (edgesMatrix.Any()) return true;`

Comment: Okay. I need to know if there exists the connection between two specific nodes(vertices) that's why I need to find index (if it exists in the _edgesMatrix) or  use lambda expression to find out the same thing, meaning if there's connection between from and to vertices. Is that possible? If so, how can I do that?

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake in my last comment. Should be `if (pairsFromMatrix.Any())...`. Thant means there exists at least one pair in `edgesMatrix` that has the same items as items `from` and `to`.

Comment: Okay. I still can't get it done. I have the code: var pairsFromMatrix = _edgesMatrix
                    .Where(em => em.Key == from && em.Value == to); And now it says cannot resolve the Key and Value symbols. I probably know why it is. It's because I have declared edgesMatrix as private List<Edge> _egdesMatrix and in the definition there's no such thing as KeyValuePair. However don't know what I can do to improve that. The defintion of KeyValuePair I have in the Edge class.

Comment: `var pairsFromMatrix = _edgesMatrix.Where(em => em.GetFromTo().Key == from && em.GetFromTo().Value == to);`

Comment: Okay. I did it exactly as you said. And Now I get the "Cannot resolve symbol GetFromTo" error message. Should I implement the method? Or maybe I should attach the using namespace to make it happen?

Comment: _edgesMatrix should be of type List<Edge>, only then you can profit from type info

Comment: Hey Tomas, I did it. I'm using dictionary instead of KeyValuePair. It works just as I wanted it to do. Thank you for your support. ;)